# Full Duplex communication using message queue, continuously printing messeges

Tags: c, ipc

**program1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SEND_KEY 2
#define RCV_KEY 3

typedef struct msgbuf 
{
    long mtype;     /* message type, must be > 0 */
    char mtext[100];  /* message data */
} MSG_BUF;
int main()
{
    int msg_id;
    MSG_BUF mbuf_snd,mbuf_rcv;

    if((msg_id=msgget(5,IPC_CREAT |0644))<0)
        perror("msgget");

    if(fork()==0)
    {
        // child is receiving
        while(1) {
            if((msgrcv(msg_id,&mbuf_rcv,sizeof(mbuf_rcv.mtext),RCV_KEY,0))<0)
                perror("msgrcv");
            printf("Message : %s\n",mbuf_rcv.mtext);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Parent is writing
        while(1){
            mbuf_snd.mtype=SEND_KEY;
            printf("Enter the message\n");
            scanf(" %[^\n]",mbuf_snd.mtext);
            if((msgsnd(msg_id,&mbuf_snd,strlen(mbuf_snd.mtext)+1,0))<0)
                perror("msgsnd");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**program2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SEND_KEY 3
#define RCV_KEY 2

typedef struct msgbuf {
        long mtype;     /* message type, must be > 0 */
        char mtext[100];  /* message data */
}MSG_BUF;
int main()
{
    int msg_id;
    MSG_BUF mbuf_snd,mbuf_rcv;
    if((msg_id=msgget(5,IPC_CREAT |0644))<0)
        perror("msgget");
    if(fork()==0)
    {
        //child is receiving 
        while(1){
            if((msgrcv(msg_id,&mbuf_rcv,sizeof(mbuf_rcv.mtext),RCV_KEY,0))<0)
                perror("msgrcv");
            printf("Message : %s\n",mbuf_rcv.mtext);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Parent is writing
        while(1){
            mbuf_snd.mtype=SEND_KEY;
            printf("Enter the message\n");
            scanf(" %[^\n]",mbuf_snd.mtext);
            if((msgsnd(msg_id,&mbuf_snd,strlen(mbuf_snd.mtext)+1,0))<0)
                perror("msgsnd");
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program1 parent is writing message for mtype 2 and child receiving message from mtype 3.

Program2 parent is writing message for mtype 3 and child receiving mesaage from mtype 2.

But after compiling it is not giving any error. But when I execute it, it is continuously printing data on screen. My requirement is it should stop after printing data and wait for next data.

Could you explain me what is happening?

Comment: "But after compiling it is not giving any error" how do you compile your programs?

Comment: for First program cc program1.c -o send and for Second program cc program2.c -o receive . and I will execute them in different windows

Comment: You should add some `-Wall` to your build command, you may see some warnings lying around...

Comment: @purplepsycho Don't know about -wall But i am not getting any warnings

Comment: By default, your compiler won't tell you about warnings unless you ask it explicitly with some `-Wall` directive. When I tried to compile your code with `gcc`, it tells my than there was no declaration of `fork()` function (declared by `<unistd.h>`)

Comment: @purplepsycho Again thanks for excellent update.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the input function:

When you call `scanf`, the `\n` stay on the input stream, and each time `scanf` is called again, `mbuf_snd.mtext` is empty and `\n` stay on the input stream...

**Fix:**

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",mbuf_snd.mtext);
```

**Explain:**

- `%[^\n]` will get the message you want,
- `%*c` will remove the `\n` from input stream. (the `*` tells `scanf` not to store the read character)

**Other method:**

You could have used `fgets` function to get a line from input stream, it is less tricky than `scanf`:

```
fgets(mbuf_snd.mtext, sizeof mbuf_snd.mtext, stdin)
```

One advantage of `fgets` is that it is easy to detect that there is no mode data to be read from input stream.

Comment: I have edited  scanf() to scanf(" %[^\n]",mbuf_snd.mtext); (one space is added before %) but still in receive program it is printing continuously.

Comment: Yes, because in that case, `scanf` has still data to read. Try adding `%*c` after the `[^\n]`

Comment: Thanks man it's working I have modified "%[^\n]" with %s and it is working, may be we have to handle '\n'